# UBUNTU 18.04.3 LTS first freezed then login loop when restarted its not booting

Tags: boot, 18.04

When I got busy for a few minutes on the phone only to see the frozen ubuntu lock screen. Then login loop. when shutdown using power button, not at all booting. Displaying 20 lines then stopping. Then boot from USB live ubuntu, tried boot-repair, no change.

Then tried the following commands:
`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`
`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
`sudo apt clean`
`sudo apt update --fix -missing`
`sudo apt install -f`
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
`sudo apt upgrade`
`sudo apt dist-upgrade`
then last but not the least `sudo reboot`.

The system booted normally, the ubuntu screens came back but again after some time, end up at login screen.

After login in and connecting to the internet, do not know, how to fix the things which failed to load.

Can we still do something from the terminal by following the screen instructions?

I also like to check boot log and find out why it exits from the boot process and coming to login screen in terminal mode, instead of proceeding to graphics mode?

The two last lines of syslog:

> Aug 16 14:15:06 syed007-K53SD rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.32.0" x-pid="1392" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
>
> Aug 16 14:15:08 syed007-K53SD Tor[1761]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 80%: Connecting to the Tor network. (Network is unreachable; NOROUTE; count 65; recommendation warn; host 4A858E2FD0C6AD66FF44430D3764143C35F9E6A9 at 5.9.153.90:12000)

[image: Login Screen]![1]

[image: After login]![2]

Comment: Take a clear picture of the screen with 20 lines with your smart phone. Then edit that image into your question so I can take a look for you.

Comment: Now only a login screen is coming with login.

Comment: Lets first check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: After all of the other problems that you've had, consider just reinstalling Ubuntu... then, until you learn more about how Ubuntu/Linux works, don't start modifying your system yet. Just run on a stock Ubuntu system first.

Comment: Used `fsck -N /dev/sda3` file system is OK.

Comment: I'm confused... are you running Ubuntu 18.04, or 17.0 of something else? You must use a Ubuntu 18.04 OR HIGHER to be able to reinstall/upgrade over your current 18.04.

Comment: @heynnema I'm thinking the same. I've Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed from USB. The problem is that when trying to install in 18.04.3 LTS, there is no re-install option as that of 17.0 except  `erase and install ubuntu`. If I select this option don't know which 0S it will erase and install ubuntu that is why omitted this option, as I don't want to lose Windows 7. When I choose another option, though it is listing all the sda's, when I choose sda3, it is choosing the option not selected. when listed all the available options in the list, listing all the file systems, confused to select one.

Comment: @heynnema I'm using 18.04.3 LTS but I recalled the 17.0 options which are missing in 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: You want to select the file system that is ext4.

Comment: Yes, want to select file system `ext4` from `Something else` option. But, when selecting the `ext4 file system`, it is asking for a `mount point`. Don't know, which folder is taken as default mount point of ubuntu? like / or /bin or /usr don't know which folder...

Comment: Also, the Syslog file stopped almost 12 hours back when log in was going into a loop. Tried to start Syslog service, any idea? just want to know why it exits to the login screen?

Comment: The mount point is /

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/index.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall